# Must declare scalar variable error when executing t-sql script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute the below script to get the mdf and ldf file details from a .back file. It throws an error

Incorrect syntax at H.

```
Declare @backupPath NVARCHAR(300);
set @backupPath =N'H:\path\of\backupfile.bak';
declare @qry NVARCHAR(max) = N'RESTORE FILELISTONLY from disk = ';
set @qry = @qry + @backupPath ;
exec(@qry)
```

When I tried with the below line
`set @qry = 'Restore filelistonly from @backuppath'`
it would throw the error "declare scalar variable @qry. 
Please help.

Comment: No repro. Something else is wrong. Maybe you have some text highlighted when you're executing the query. SSMS only executes whatever is highlighted in the query window.

Comment: cannot reproduce the error, works fine here

Comment: Can't reproduce either. Think @Will has likely hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Is that really your exact error? Does it not give you a line? _"When I tried with the below line"_ What does that mean? Are you trying to run this line-by-line by highlighting and running them separately? Then you don't have a script.

Comment: I think you might be missing the single quotes when concatenating the path and the @qry.  Tried it like this and it works: 
`set @qry = @qry +  '''' + @backuppath + '''' ;`

Comment: if you add `print @qry` instead of `exec (@qry)` the error should be apparent - presumably the *generated* sql needs to includes quotes around the path? right now it doesn't

Comment: Thanks @RigertaDemiri

Answer (score 2):

If you print @qry you will see that syntax is wrong, the quotes are missing.

Try this:

```
Declare @backupPath NVARCHAR(300);
set @backupPath =N'''H:\path\of\backupfile.bak''';
declare @qry NVARCHAR(max) = N'RESTORE FILELISTONLY from disk = ';
set @qry = @qry + @backupPath ;
exec(@qry)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ezin82. Your query worked. My query still has an  issue. I am wondering why my question was downvoted. Thanks again for the help